# Resolution problem

Tags: graphics-card, display, resolution

We have several computer with different graphics cards. Each graphics cards produces the different display (very slight pixels) even though we have a same resolution like 1024x768. do you have any suggestion to overcome this situation? I want all the monitor should provide the same display.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "Each graphics cards produces the different display (very slight pixels)"? Please elaborate further.

Comment: How are the graphics cards connected to the monitor? VGA? DVI-D? DVI-A? HDMI? DisplayPort?

Comment: @MikeScott, it is connected with VGA.

Comment: @Adam543i, Slight pixel means, one monitor display with sharp line, but other monitors display the line with some blurred as Kien mentioned below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help you out with your question if all the monitors are the same it wouldn't matter which resolution you set for. The video card you're using they're all going to support that resolution "1024x768" with no problem regardless how much memory your video card has or one is higher then the other. The rule of thumb is always set the resolution what your LCD monitor preffers in order to get the sharpness so for example you picked up and lcd 19" it says resolution supports up to 1400x900 that's the highest it gets but it can also go lower the only problem going lower it basically means you no longer get that proper sharpeness that the lcd monitor can provide. It will always look kinda blurry. If you're concern about the fonts and icons being too small at a higher resolution you're better off changing that feature in windows to make your fonts bigger and icon bigger.

So another words don't worry about what kinda video/monitors each computer is using set to what the lcd monitor can provide simply changing the windows view, fonts size, icon size on the application that will fix your problem.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your response. I agree with your response and this(blur) is what happened. However, is there any possible to overcome this? I need the same kind of display in across the monitors when I use the same resolution.

Comment: The blur that I'm reffering too is ghosting are you seeing any ghosting background? it's usually more noticeble on bright background such as white. The best thing to do is have a darker background to work with. However you're still going to encounter this issue when you're working with a word document or an email which by default it's white background. There's really no other way to make it sharp because you're some what downgrading the monitor's resolution when it needs to optimize by it's highest resolution output that it can perform.